# Why are the initialization of a string from a function with std::string and std::string& similar?

Tags: c++, string, assembly, substring

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  const std::string name = "test test test";

  const std::string st = name.substr(0, 7);
  const std::string& st2 = name.substr(0, 7);
}
```

I am aware of the theoretical difference, but looking at the assembly code shows no difference at all at -O2. See below:

st :

```
mov     ecx, 7
xor     edx, edx
lea     rdi, [rsp+32]
mov     rsi, rsp
call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const
```

st2:

```
mov     ecx, 7
xor     edx, edx
lea     rdi, [rsp+64]
mov     rsi, rsp
call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const
```

Comment: Why do you think it would be different? The one by reference still has to call the function, and since its a `const &`, it's extending the life of the temporary object.

Comment: Is there a theoretical difference?

Comment: what else did you expect?

Comment: *"theoretical"* and *asm* is different thing anyway.

Comment: Const references can extend the life of temporary objects, like the result of a function that returns by value. The way this works is not well defined, but most implementations will turn that reference into  an object behind the scene and invisibly to the developer. And I think may users here are forgetting that this behavior is not intuitive and should be surprising the first time it is encountered.

Comment: "*I am aware of the theoretical difference*": I suggest you add an explanation of what you think the theoretical differences are. Given the behavior of this program on the abstract machine, it should not really be surprising that the asm does the same of both lines. I think it is likely that you have a misunderstanding in what the theoretical differences are or you did not communicate what you find surprising well.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the whole program boiled down to `xor eax, eax; ret;` assembly, since this is the only observable effect of the source code.

Comment: With what compiler and C++ library?  GCC and libstdc++?  clang and libc++?  Some mix of those?  We can rule out MSVC because of the calling convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the initialization of `st`, because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), the return value of `name.substr` is directly constructed into the string object named `st`.  In the case of `st2`, the return value is directly constructed into a unnamed temporary object and `st2` is initialized with a reference to this unnamed object.

In both cases the result of `name.substr` is constructed into an object of automatic storage duration that's local to main without copying or moving. The only difference is that this object has a name in the first case and doesn't in the second case. There's no reason for the compiler to generate different code for creating these two objects.

(Binding the temporary object to a const reference also extends the lifetime of the temporary, giving the temporary the same lifetime as `st`. This effectively gives the temporary the name `st2`, making it effectively identical to the object named `st`.  However, because this is done in the last statement of the function, this doesn't have a significant effect in your example.)

Comment: If we were compiling without optimization, I'd expect the code *after* the constructor calls to differ.  `std::string& st2` is a reference to an object, so we'd expect a `mov` store of the `lea     rdi, [rsp+64]` pointer into an 8-byte location also on the stack.  With `st`, the named object *is* the string so there's no need to store a pointer to it anywhere.  (With optimization enabled, actually storing the `st2` pointer anywhere presumably gets optimized away.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Without optimization there's a store to the reference, yes, but I don't know if that's significant here since the original poster was talking about compiling with optimization.

Comment: Right.  My point was that the source lines aren't 100% identical in terms of C++ abstract machine(ry), and they only compile identically because part of the reference one optimized away.  In case that wasn't clear to all future readers from the way you phrased it.  But yes, agreed there's no reason for different asm for *creating* the two `std::string` objects.